# Return list of previously uploaded files back to flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn Flask by making a simple data comparison tool (using kolmogorov-smirnov) by extending [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) tutorial, for which I am getting stuck in 'remembering' the list of uploaded files that should be given to the function that will perform the kolmogorov-smirnov testing.

I have tried several options, but as of yet have been unable to get the list of previously selected and uploaded files to appear in my dummy template (foo.html). The question therefore is if my idea (of handing a variable to the template, and getting it back from the template) is a bad idea to begin with, and if so how should this be done?

test.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './uploads/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt','arw'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    filenames = []
    for file in uploaded_files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
    return render_template('upload.html', filenames=filenames)

@app.route('/ks_test', methods=['POST'])
def ks_test(filenames):
    return render_template('foo.html', content=filenames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    debug=True
  )
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">How To Upload a File.</h3>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
   <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" multiple="" name="file[]" class="span3" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="span2">
   </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Uploaded files</h3>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
   This is a list of the files you just uploaded, click on them to load/download them
   <ul>
    {% for file in filenames %}
     <li>{{file}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   <hr/>
   <!-- How to return the filenames list back to the python part? -->
   <form action="ks_test" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="files" value={{ filenames }}>
     <input type="submit" value="Kolmogorov-Smirnov test">  
   </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

foo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ content }}</pre>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The error that the above snippet gives is a `TypeError`, as I haven't figured out how to return a variable and thus the function is expecting an input variable which it never receives.

```
TypeError: ks_test() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

**Update 1**

I have gotten a bit further, to a state where I am able to retrieve 1 item from the list of uploaded files by using the following changed functions:

test.py

```
@app.route('/ks_test', methods=['POST','GET'])
def ks_test():
    filenames = request.form.getlist('filenames')
    return render_template('foo.html', content=filenames)
```

upload.html

```
   <form action="ks_test" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="filenames" value={{ filenames }}>
     <input type="submit" value="Kolmogorov-Smirnov test">  
   </form>
```

foo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <ul>
    {% for i in content %}
      <li>{{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, this this only retrieves 1 element of `{{ filenames }}` as demonstrated by the following output if one file was uploaded.

- ['D-00342-serum-D7_Emission_1.txt']

while it yields the following output if multiple items were uploaded:

- ['D-00342-serum-D6_Emission_1.txt',

Note the clear indication of the list not being finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story... don't try to do this, use `session` instead as described below. However, if there is a more correct/better way to do this please let me know.

test.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, session
from werkzeug import secure_filename

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'xyz'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './uploads/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt','arw'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    filenames = []
    for file in uploaded_files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
    # This line is essential, store the data in session
    session['filenames'] = filenames
    return render_template('upload.html', filenames=filenames)

@app.route('/ks_test')
def ks_test():
    return render_template('foo.html', content=session['filenames'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    debug=True
  )
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Uploaded files</h3>
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div>
   This is a list of the files you just uploaded, click on them to load/download them
   <ul>
    {% for file in filenames %}
     <li><a href="{{url_for('uploaded_file', filename=file)}}">{{file}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   <hr/>
   <form action="ks_test">
     <input type="submit" value="Kolmogorov-Smirnov test">  
   </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

foo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <ul>
    {% for i in content %}
      <li>{{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

which yields the following output if two files are selected:

```
* D-00342-serum-D6_Emission_1.txt
* D-00342-serum-D7_Emission_1.txt
```